# Self cancelling the task with OperationCanceledException

Tags: c#, async-await, task, cancellation

I noticed that task can cancel itself by throwing `OperationCanceledException`. Normally, one can pass a user friendly reason in the `OperationCanceledException`[constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfcfy805%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that later becomes the exception message. However, it doesn't look that way in the task scenario. The exception makes task canceled but eventually gets translated into `TaskCanceledException` and the original message is replaced with generic one.

Is there a neat way to state the cancellation reason in this example? I looked at `CancellationTokenSource` but didn't see an option neither.

```
  class Program
  {
    static async Task MyAsyncMethod()
    {
      await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
      throw new OperationCanceledException("My lost cancellation reason");
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var task = MyAsyncMethod();
      try
      {
        task.Wait();
      }
      catch (AggregateException ecxeptions)
      {
        var exception = ecxeptions.InnerException;
        Console.WriteLine(exception.GetType());       //TaskCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);         //A task was canceled.
        Console.WriteLine(task.Status);               //Canceled
        Console.WriteLine(task.Exception == null);    //true
      }

      Console.Read();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This only happens when you use `Task.Wait` which creates a new `AggregateException` that bundles all the inner exceptions.

If you use `await` the actual exception is thrown and will have the correct message. Since you can't use `await` in `Main` you can use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` which will block synchronously but will still produce the same exception as `await` will (without the aggregation):

```
static async Task MyAsyncMethod()
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    throw new TaskCanceledException("My lost cancellation reason");
}

static void Main()
{
    var task = MyAsyncMethod();
    try
    {
        task.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception.GetType()); // TaskCanceledException
        Console.WriteLine(exception.Message); // My lost cancellation reason
        Console.WriteLine(task.Status); // Canceled
        Console.WriteLine(task.Exception == null); // true
    }

    Console.Read();
}
```